# Determine the length of **DC** in terms of $l_1$ and $l_2$

Tags: geometry, circles

> [image]
>
> In the given figure, **E** is the midpoint of the arc
> **ABEC** and **ED** is perpendicular to the chord **BC**
> at **D**. If the length of the chord **AB** is $l_1$, and that of
> **BD** is $l_2$, determine the length of **DC** in terms of $l_1$
> and $l_2$

[Source](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is $DC=l_1+l_2$.

Indeed, let $\theta=\angle EBC=\angle EAC$. We have also $\theta=\angle ECA$. Using the "sine law" we have $$\frac{AC}{\sin2\theta}=\frac{EC}{\sin\theta}$$
Thus $AC=(2\cos\theta) EC$. Also $\cos\theta=\dfrac{BD}{BE}$, so $l_2=(\cos\theta) BE$. This implies that
$$AC\cdot BE=2l_2 EC\tag{1}$$
Now, since $ACEB$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, we have
$$
BC\cdot AE=AC\cdot BE+ AB\cdot EC
$$
Using (1) and recalling that $AE=EC$ we get
$$
BC\cdot EC=2l_2\cdot EC+ l_1\cdot EC
$$
Simplifying, we get $BC=2 l_2+l_1$, so $CD=l_2+l_1$. $\qquad\square$

Comment: I am confused in which triangle you used the sine law

Comment: @Buraian, Triangle $AEC$.